# Select table and column dynamically based on other table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table and values,

```
Tb_name         column_name1    column_name2
Citator_KTLO_CC Date_Created    Date_Modified
Citator_KTLO_QA Date_Created    Date_Modified
```

I want to select dynamically column from table, so the result is like this:

```
Select Date_Created,Date_Modified from Citator_KTLO_CC
```

and in next loop it will select for second row, like

```
Select Date_Created,Date_Modified from Citator_KTLO_QA
```

How can i do this by using dynamic sql ?

any example are appreciated.

Comment: can you post example data for both tables and an example of what your result set should look like ?

Comment: if you want someone to help you than you have to make clear what you need. How else can we help you ?

Comment: any hibernate method to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example of how to do this.
Since you dont post many info I just assume that the table containing all the tablenames is called 'tables'

Also this will only work if all tables have the same column types.

```
-- create a test table you dont need this
create table tables (tb_name varchar(100) primary key, field1 varchar(100), field2 varchar(100))

-- fill my test table you dont need this
insert into tables values ('table1', 'field1', 'field2')
insert into tables values ('table2', 'foo1', 'foo2')
insert into tables values ('table3', 'test1', 'test2')

-- this is the actual code you need, replace the names with your real names
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
declare @tb_name varchar(100) = ''
declare @field1 varchar(100) = ''
declare @field2 varchar(100) = ''

declare myCursor cursor for
  select tb_name, field1, field2 from tables -- dont know how your table is called

open myCursor
fetch next from myCursor into @tb_name, @field1, @field2
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  set @sql = @sql + ' select ' + @field1 + ', ' + @field2 + ' from ' +  @tb_name + ' union all '
  fetch next from myCursor into @tb_name, @field1, @field2
end
close myCursor
deallocate myCursor 

select @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 10) 

exec (@sql)
```

**EDIT:**
using a where clause is possible but things will get more complicated

```
declare @something date = getdate()

set @sql = @sql + ' select ' + @field1 + ', ' + @field2 + ' from ' +  @tb_name + ' where ' + @field1 + ' = ' + @something + ' union all '
```

You can use the example above to build what you need just play with it.

**EDIT:**
using a where clause with a date format

```
declare @something date = getdate()

set @sql = @sql + ' select ' + @field1 + ', ' + @field2 + ' from ' +  @tb_name + ' where ' + @field1 + ' = ''' + CONVERT(varchar(8), @something, 112) + ''' union all '
```

Comment: Also when you find it helpfull you can give my answer an upvote

Comment: its working here can you replace the line exec (@sql) with this : select convert(varchar(2000), @sql) and then post the result here ?

Comment: Yes got it ..Thanks

Comment: how can i use where condition in above query

Comment: I edited my answer with an example you will have to do some playing with it but this should get you on your way

Comment: Its working for varchar datatype but not for date ....Getting error like The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: can you replace exec(@sql) by select @sql and then show me the result ?

Comment: Yes here it is....select Record_Key,Project_ID,Task_ID,Record_ID_
  from ##Table1 where CONVERT(date,Date_Created) = 2016-06-27    the date should be in quote

Comment: = 2016-06-27 has to be = '20160627' than it will work. Date values must be in single quotes and the format yyyyMMdd is universal so it will work on every sql server with any regional settings

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer with an example on how to get the single quotes and how to format the date to this format

Comment: Yes got it ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000); 

SET @SQL = '

SELECT  *
FROM    Citator_KTLO_CC
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    Citator_KTLO_QA;'

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
For selecting one row if you are running in aloop

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' select ' + column_name_1 + ',' + column_name2 + ' from ' + Tb_name
FROM < yourtable >
EXEC (@sql)
```

OR

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @sql = 'union all select ' + column_name_1 + ',' + column_name2 + ' from ' + Tb_name
FROM < yourtable >


SET @sql =stuff(@sql,1,10,'')
EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. If you've more than two cols, you can use dynamic sql to generate a list of cols to then generate more dynamic sql instead of hard coding.

```
DROP TABLE #Test

CREATE TABLE #Test 
(Tb_name  NVARCHAR(15),
 column_name1    NVARCHAR(12),
 column_name2 NVARCHAR(13));

 INSERT INTO #Test VALUES
('Citator_KTLO_CC','Date_Created','Date_Modified'),
('Citator_KTLO_QA','Date_Created','Date_Modified');

DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + Cols + ' FROM '+TbL 
 FROM (SELECT QUOTENAME(Tb_name) TBL,
      QUOTENAME(column_name1) + ', '+
      QUOTENAME(column_name2) Cols
      FROM #Test) Blah
 FOR XML PATH('')),1,10,''))

 PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ColumnList1 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''''''; 
DECLARE @ColumnList2 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''''''; 

DECLARE @ColumnNameFromTable1 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @ColumnNameFromTable2 VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE MyCursor1 CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'Citator_KTLO_CC'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

DECLARE MyCursor2 CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'Citator_KTLO_QA'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

OPEN MyCursor1
OPEN MyCursor2

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor1 INTO @ColumnNameFromTable1; 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 

        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor2 INTO @ColumnNameFromTable2; 

        SET @ColumnList1 = @ColumnList1 + ',' + @ColumnNameFromTable1 
        SET @ColumnList2 = @ColumnList2 + ',' + @ColumnNameFromTable2 

        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor1 INTO @ColumnNameFromTable1; 
    END

CLOSE MyCursor1;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor1;

CLOSE MyCursor2;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor2;

EXEC ('SELECT ' + @ColumnList1 + ' FROM Citator_KTLO_CC UNION ALL SELECT ' + 

 @ColumnList2 + ' FROM Citator_KTLO_QA ')
```